# What does it mean "Remember to set the ScreenUpdating property back to True when your macro ends"?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

It's said in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb221605(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
But because I'm limited in English, I don't quite understand the sentence.

I'm playing around to test it with something like this

```
Sub test1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Range("A1:A200"): cell.Select: Next
End Sub
```

Run the test1 sub, cell A200 is selected - but on the sheet I still can see row 1, I don't see cell A200.

Although I doubt that I will see cell A200 with the next sub, anyway I guess maybe the sentence in the link means something like this : "with the kind of test1 sub, if `application.screenupdating = true` is put before the `end sub`, then I can see cell A200"

So I make test2 sub:

```
Sub test2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Range("A1:A200"): Cell.Select: Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Run the test2 sub, the same result, I still don't see cell A200, although cell A200 is selected.

Next, I make another sub

```
Sub test3()
For Each cell In Range("A1:A200"): cell.Select: Next
End Sub
```

I run test1 sub, then directly run test3 sub.
When the sub test3 is being run, it does select each cell until I can see cell A200 after test3 sub finish.

So for the time being, my conclusion is weird:
*"**No need** to remember to set the ScreenUpdating property back to True when your macro ends"*
because my conclusion seems "against" the sentence in that link

Except.... 
if I assume the sentence *"when your macro ends"* ---> means *"when a part of codes ends"*. So, it's something like this :

```
Sub test4()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Range("A1:A200"): cell.Select: Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Selection.Select
End Sub
```

Because it only my own assumption, I am curious what exactly *"Remember to set the ScreenUpdating property back to True when your macro ends."* mean ?

Any kind of response would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating

Comment: @Lundt, the sentence being questioned in the link I post is almost the same link you put in your comment. Thank you.

Comment: ScreenUpdating is *automatically* reset when your code ends.  You only need to set it back to True if you want to see some intermediate state while your code is still running (but you may for example need to add some DoEvents for that to happen)

Comment: When you select a cell with ScreenUpdating on, the selected cell is scrolled into view if it's not already visible.  That doesn't happen with ScreenUpdating  off.

Answer (score 1):

When you disable updates, the set  of operations is fast, because the ui won’t update after each operation in the set. However, you need to re-enable (or more precisely, restore) the state of this property, to allow future operations (in the script) to update the ui.

If you want to see the effect of the last cell selection, then select the cell again *after* re-enabling ui updates.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Jiri. But I'm sorry, in my side if I don't re-enable the ScreenUpdating just before the `end sub` of sub test1, then I directly run the sub test3, the ScreenUpdating enable by itself.  It seems that once the sub finish, it automatically set the ScreenUpdating to True. It's different case with EnableEvents ---> If I don't set to true the EnableEvents just before the `End Sub`, then when I run another sub, the EnableEvents still false. So, if it's the EnableEvents, then I have to _remember to set the EnableEvents property back to True when my macro ends_.

Comment: Yes, the ScreenUpdating property is reset when the code execution finishes. If it wasn't, you would not be able to work with the sheet after exiting the sub. But if you change it's value inside your sub, you should always restore it, because your sub can be called from other subs that might rely on it. I believe it's better not to always set it back to true, but to the original value that you save at the beginning of your sub.